# How to link dependencies when compiling extern "C" {...}?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I am using Python's `ctypes` to interface with some `C++` code and have added a dependency that I cannot seem to link to at compile time.  (This dependency links fine for any uses other than this `extern "C" {...}` code.)

I include my `C++` in the `_extern.cpp` file below:

```
// cellComplex_extern.cpp

#include "../../../cell.hpp"

extern "C" {...}
```

The header file `cell.hpp` includes my dependency, and here is where the problem begins.  **The compiler (of course) cannot find `"interval.hpp` or `hess_ari.hpp`** because in the Makefile below I have not made the link...

```
//cell.hpp
#include "interval.hpp"  
#include "hess_ari.hpp"
```

as you can see:

```
# Makefile
export CXSCINCDIR = ${HOME}/local/cxsc/include                                        
export CXSCLIBDIR = ${HOME}/local/cxsc/lib                                            

CXXINC   = -I$(CXSCINCDIR)   
LIBPATHS = -L$(CXSCLIBDIR)                                          
CXXFLAGS =   $(CXXINC)       

cellComplex_extern:

  g++  -c -fPIC cellComplex_extern.cpp -o cellComplex_extern.o                       
  g++  -shared -Wl -o cellComplex_lib.so cellComplex_extern.o
```

**Why have I not made the link?** Because the only way I know how is to do something like

```
g++ -I$(CXSCINCDIR) cellComplex_extern.cpp -o cellComplex_extern.o -L$(CXSCLIBPATHS) -lcxsc
```

Which is not going to work here since I don't have a `main` function in `cellComplex_extern.cpp`.

Any tips?

**EDIT:** Okay, the answer is below and here's my new makefile which works great:

```
export CXSCINCDIR = ${HOME}/local/cxsc/include                                        
export CXSCLIBDIR = ${HOME}/local/cxsc/lib                                            
export CXX = g++                                                                      

CXXINC   = -I$(CXSCINCDIR)    #-I$(GSLINCDIR)
LIBPATHS = -L$(CXSCLIBDIR)    #-L$(GSLLIBDIR)                                         
CXXFLAGS =   $(CXXINC)        #$(CXXOPTS)

cellComplex_extern:

  g++  $(CXXINC) -c -fPIC cellComplex_extern.cpp -o cellComplex_extern.o             
  g++  $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -Wl -o cellComplex_lib.so cellComplex_extern.o $(LIBPATHS) -lcxsc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your problem correctly, but can't you give the include path to the compiler as in

```
g++ -I$(CXSCINCDIR) -c -fPIC cellComplex_extern.cpp -o cellComplex_extern.o
```

?